# What does "logically equivalent" mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[In this video](http://www.larsoncalculus.com/calc10/content/proof-videos/chapter-9/section-4/proof-direct-comparison-test/) a proof is given for the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)
and the presenter says that the proof for $$a_j \ge c_j \ge 0$$
$$\implies \text{ if } \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j \text{ diverges, then } \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j \text{ diverges.}$$

is "logically equivalent" as the proof for convergent sequences.

I understand what it means (that one can "reverse"/negate the conditions and get the other proof), but am having difficulties understanding "logically equivalent"? Equivalent means that "are the same" and logically means that the statements **are the same logically**? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right idea.

In general, two propositions $P$ and $Q$ are "logically equivalent" when 
$$ P \Leftrightarrow Q$$
is always true. Thus $P$ and $Q$ should always have the same truth value.

EDIT:

In the particular case above, $P$ is the statement "if $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} a_j$ converges, then $ \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} c_j$ converges" and $Q$ is the statement "if $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} c_j$ diverges, then $ \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} a_j$ diverges". To see that both statements are equivalent, note that $P$ can be written in terms of atomic statements as $P_1 \Rightarrow P_2$, where $P_1$ is the atomic statement "$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} a_j$ converges" and $P_2$ is the atomic statement "$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} c_j$ converges". Using these atomic statements, the statement $Q$ can be written as $\neg P_2 \Rightarrow \neg P_1$ as the negation of "converges" is "diverges". The statement $\neg P_2 \Rightarrow \neg P_1$ is called the contrapositive of $P_1 \Rightarrow P_2$ and it is well-known that these statements are logically equivalent. This can be shown by constructing a truth table.

In case you want to read more about such topics I highly recommend the excellent book *Proof, Logic and Conjecture: A Mathematician's toolbox* by S.Wolf.

Comment: Is there maybe some more to it? Writing $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ in my example would mean thats $\sum c_j$ diverges $\implies$ $\sum a_j$ diverges and $\sum a_j$ diverges $\implies$ $\sum c_j$ diverges? Maybe something has to be negated? What are $P$ and $Q$ in my example?

Comment: $P$ is "$\sum a_j$ converges implies $\sum c_j$ converges" and $Q$ is "$\sum c_j$ diverges implies $\sum a_j$ diverges."  They are logically equivalent statements because they are contrapositive of each other.

Comment: @KyleMiller How does one demonstrate the contrapositiveness? In addition to just claiming so?

Comment: @mavavilj Contrapositives to true implications are just logically true.  This seems to be an explanation: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1870180/172988

Comment: @mavavilj I also tend to explain this with a concrete everyday example.  Say "If it is raining, there are puddles on the ground."  Then, "if there are no puddles on the ground, it is not raining."  The second statement is the contrapositive of the first.

Comment: If A then always B, is equivalent never both A and not B, which is equivalent to if not B then never A.  Consider "if I'm home then I will turn the lights on".  You drive by and the lights are off.  "Hmmm, " you say, "I guess he's not home".  "I turn the lights on when I am home" is equivalent to "if the lights are off, I'm not home."

Comment: I am sorry for not answering your question at once. I see @KyleMiller explained the concept in your particular case. However, I was so free to edit my question for possible future readers. I hope it answers your question now entirely.